# Probability of a Rare Event Occurring within a Certain Number of Times

Tags: probability, statistics

I'd like to know how to find the probability of an event occurring, given the probability of that event, within a certain number of chances for it to occur.

For example, say that once every year there is an event that can either occur or not. There is a 1/5,000,000 chance of that event occurring during that year. You live 60 years. What is the probability that of one of those events will occur during your lifetime?

Answer (score 2):

$$Pr[X \text{ occurs at least once in sixty years }]$$
$$ = 1 - Pr[X \text{ occurs never in sixty years}] = 1 - Pr[X \text{ does not occur in a given year}]^{60}$$
$$ = 1-(1-1/5 000 000)^{60}$$

Answer (score 1):

One of the other answers gives an exact solution, but if your number of chances for the event to occur are somewhat large and the probability of the event occurring in one trial is very small, then on a computer you may run into underflow errors and/or inaccuracies with floating point arithmetic. A very good approximation, provided that the probability of the event occurring in one trial is small, and the number of trials is not too big, is to define $\lambda = pn$ where $p$ is the probability of the event occurring in one trial and $n$ is the number of trials. Then the probability of at least one event is essentially the probability given under the Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda$ (which is a very good approximation under the conditions stipulated), and this is given by $1 - e^{-\lambda}$ and this could be much more stable to compute if $p$ is much smaller compared $\lambda = np$.

Furthermore, if $\lambda$ is so small that $e^{-\lambda}$ evaluates to be $1$ under floating point arithmetic, then $\lambda$ itself is a very very good approximation for $1 - e^{-\lambda}$ so you can just use that.

Comment: Instead of trying to compute arbitrarily many terms of the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\lambda^{n}e^{-\lambda}}{n!}$, isn't it better to simply look at $1-e^{-\lambda}$?

Having said this, you're spot on about the benefits of using the Poisson approximation for this probability, and I didn't consider that this may be a better option than working out $1-(1-1/5000000)^{60}$

Comment: @Walter You're absolutely right, I missed the $1 - e^{-\lambda}$ result. I'll update with that. But yes my point is that by working with $\lambda = np$ you may have better floating point results (and faster computation) working with $1 - e^{-\lambda}$ than $1 - p$.

Comment: I mean, if $n$ is large. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate the calculation of [Walter](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/241637/walter) by the expression:

$$1-(1-1/5 000 000)^{60}\approx 1-e^{-1.2\cdot 10^{-5}}$$ The approximation is sufficient, because 60 is large enough.

*Off-Topic: The username of Walter is Stanley now.*

In both cases it is $1-0.99998800007$

The approximation is done by applying the relation:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty } \left( 1+\frac{x}{n} \right)^n=e^x$$